# how to sort substrings separated by blanks in a string

Tags: java, string, sorting

how can the elements inside a String separated by blank spaces be sorted.I have  the following String:

```
  temp = abcd bcda gfre dfgre fwft efwe

   //temp.size() gives 30
   //after the sort temp should look like ie temp = abcd bcda dfgre efwe fwft gfre
```

I need to sort the elements in temp in the least possible time.Please note that the size of temp that i am dealing with is of the order of 10 to the power 7.I forgot to mention that i have tried Collections.sort and Array.sort which are taking too much time than required.What i require is a faster algorithm than that?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? (There are two or three tasks here - splitting, sorting and potentially joining...)

Comment: Split the string into words, sort the array of words.

Comment: Do you have a preference on a sorting algorithm you want to use?

Comment: I would highly recommend usage of a binary list. We are dealing with `String`, which implements `Comparable`. This will be an easy way to sort elements. One thing I would recommend would be something along the lines of: `public final class BinaryList<E extends Comparable<E>> {`.

Comment: To add onto my previous comment: Why choose a binary-searching algorithm? Well, it will be more optimized than the one that `Arrays.sort()` uses. Since you have so many elements, optimization is key. You want to use a binary searching algorithm to find the index the element would be at.

Comment: if you want sorting i don't know any algorithm without some pre conditions less than `O(n log n )`

Comment: Are all the strings 4 chars long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String [] array = temp.split("\\s+"); // split by whitespace
Arrays.sort(array); // sort using mergesort with insertionsort

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(temp.length());

 for(String s : array){
     sb.append(s).append(" "); 
 }

temp = sb.toString(); // assign temp the new string
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Split the String using `.split(seperator)`
2. Sort using Collections `Arrays.sort()`